# Jquery video delay on mouseenter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, delay

I have a video thumbnail effect where when the user hovers on the picture the video shows and starts playing. It works nice, but when I try to apply a delay method to show video, it doesn't work properly.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.img-video', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
  $(this).next().trigger('play').show();

  $(this).next().mouseout(function() {
        $(this).hide().trigger('pause')[0].currentTime = 0;
    $(this).prev().show();
    });
})
```

JSFiddle example here https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/204575/

Thank you for any advice

Comment: What is it apply to delay?

Comment: delay to show video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a named `Timeout` function and clear it if the hover is very fast. If the hover is long, then display the video.

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.img-video', function(e) {
  var image = $(this);
  
  var imageTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    image.data('imageTimer', null);
    image.hide();
    image.next().trigger('play').show();
  }, 2000);
  image.data('imageTimer', imageTimer);

  image.next().mouseout(function() {
    image.next().hide().trigger('pause')[0].currentTime = 0;
    image.show();
  });
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.img-video', function(e) {
  var image = $(this);
  var imageTimer = $(this).data('imageTimer');
  if (imageTimer !== null) {
      window.clearTimeout(imageTimer);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.sample {
  display:none;
}

.col{
  position:relative;
}
.sample{
      position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-video"  src="https://usclub.kz/temp/mcu/3.jpg" width="320" height="200"/>
       <video class="sample" muted="muted" preload loop>
         <source src="https://www.lvmagnet.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/video-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         No video support
       </video>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-video" src="https://usclub.kz/temp/mcu/1.jpg" width="320" height="200"/>
       <video class="sample" muted="muted" preload loop>
         <source src="https://www.lvmagnet.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/video-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         No video support
       </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for advice, the script is good, but breaks when I try hover too fast.

Comment: A very good point, I've updated my answer using a Timeout function. You would have to make some css changes so that the video displays in the same location as the image (for the 2nd one). Otherwise it will again break.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ray. Now it works perfect and smooth.